# cloud run to cloud run intermittent latency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, microservices, google-cloud-run

I have service A, a REST API service.
Second service B, a websocket service.
I put both service in one VPC, service A connect to B using cloud run generated URL.
I monitor both service using newrelic, especially service A connection to B.
But there is an issues, sometimes service A connection to B increase in latency to almost 6-8 seconds. Its happens several times a days even though in monitoring service B there is no sign of latency increasing.

After I update service A request to B through public IP(load balancer), there is no intermittent latency increase anymore.

What I know this is not ideal, why I need to access my service through IP public even though they are at same VPC.

Is this cloud run issues? anyone experience the same thing with me?

[update]

Networking setting enable on `Only route requests to private IPs through the VPC connector`
Because of this, service A can't directly request to service B through cloud run url.

I have to setup proxy/squid proxy(deployed with compute engine) as middleware inside VPC
I also setup service B min instance to 1 and `CPU is only allocated during request processing`

Comment: Cloud Run is not in your VPC. The URL is a public IP address. Check the Cloud Run logs to determine what the 6-8 second delay is. Most likely cold start time. It is not clear what you have configured with a load balancer. Perhaps health checks are keeping your containers warm.

Comment: what do you mean cloudrun not in my VPC? because i have setting network and subnet using my VPC. based on my monitoring show that 6-8 second delay is because of http request to service B, which in the same VPC. cold start time is not relevant, because cold start time state doesnt receive traffic at all. i set my service B to min instance 1, and always have traffic.

Comment: Cloud Run is not in your VPC, Cloud Run is in a Google network. Traffic is received by the  GFE and waits for your container to respond. You are making assumptions that are not correct. Go back to the logs and review how long it takes for the problem request to complete. Then look for a previous entry regarding starting the container. Edit your post with details.

Comment: ahh i see, my mistake. i already check the logs and there is none. my instance always 1 even when latency increase happen. there is no upscalling or downscalling.

Comment: So your container starts and is never stopped? Idle containers are stopped unless they receive constant requests or you have always-on CPU enabled. Again details help.

Comment: I have update more details at my post

Comment: Have a look at this [thread](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Communication-from-Cloud-run-to-Cloud-run/m-p/494029) & github [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48539)